# Android Studio - Layout above another layout

Tags: android, layout

I'm develoing an Android Studio app that should receive data via bleutooth.
Currently my app has a list with the paired device and a panel where the data received is shown, but both of them are on the same screen(layout). I wanna make the PairedDevice List to be displayed over the entire screen and when I choose a device, that list do become invisible and the panel with the data to appear. I'm not sure how to do it, heres my code for the interface:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/list_background"
tools:context=".ListDeviceActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/DataExchange"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DataTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Data:"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textSize="20dp"></TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:textSize="20dp"></TextView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/LcdPlayAndPause"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="Lcd_Pause">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/PlayAndPause"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="Bluetooth_Pause">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Zero"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="Zero"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Unit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"

        android:text="Unit">
    </Button>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/title"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Paired Devices"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp">

    </TextView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/pairedlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="150dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Remove this attribute from your listView android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple.
Initially set up the list to be match_parent to the height and set the panel layout to be gone. and in the onClick method for the list of items just make the list to be gone and set the panel visibility to VISIBLE.  It appears that you have used the attribute to be "invisible" but instead you can make it "gone".

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/DataExchange"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

in this way you can make it gone until the onClick is executed and later you can do this in your list of devices,

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```